# Two misplaced bags unknown box

Tags: set-identification

Son got into the Christmas stash.
I have random bags with 603R1. Which set did they come from?? Thanks.

Comment: Please add clear pictures showing the elements included within each bag. The code you've mentioned cannot be used to identify the set.